# Filter date by values not condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I would like to filter my table based on a date column that is formatted to show only the year.
Manually I just go to the filter --> filter by value and check only the year I am interested in.

How can I do this in Apps Script?
[image: google sheet screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

#### Select by Date

```
function selectbydate(dt) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const sr = 2;//data startrow
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf()
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().filter(r => {
    let d = new Date(r[26]);
    let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf();
    return dv == dtv;
  }); 
  return vs;
}
```

Comment: i am not looking to sort but to filter by value. not filter by condition like DateAfter etc, but by a value as you can see in the screenshot. Currently i have this : 
var flt_criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenDateAfter(filterdate).build();      But this is filtering by condition. I cant find the right method in the documentation for value filtering.

Comment: let filter = table.createFilter();
  let criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues([2020,2021]).build();
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(column_index, criteria);

Comment: Yeah I don't use filters.  I prefer to do it my way.